# Illegal Argument Exception: Unable to access BASE URL: httpHDP Installation

Tags: hadoop, installation, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I'm trying to install HDP2.3 with ambari. I had already installed ambari client and server. In three nodes. When I'm selecting stack - I'm getting unable to access BASE URL error. Please see below error image. [image: error]

Also in server logs, I can see the Error as:

> Resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install hdp-select' returned 1. Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: HDP-2.3. Please verify its path and try again

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

for me maintaining the Internet-Proxy solved the issue.
[Link](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.1.0/bk_ambari_reference_guide/content/_how_to_set_up_an_internet_proxy_server_for_ambari.html)

Kind regards,
Roman